# Python - Multiprocess shared memory with python numpy array?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

Here i have a 2 numpy arrays, and a function that will take those arrays as an input, and then do some numpy calculation and return the result. It works as it is but it's slow and i think we can use multiprocessing to make it a bit faster.

Anyway, here's my code :

```
A = #4 dimensions big numpy array
B = #1 dimension numpy array

def function(A, B):
    P = np.einsum("ijkl,ij->kl", A, B)
    return P.astype(np.uint8)

result = function(A,B)
```

I'm still quite new into this Multiprocessing stuff, but think that we're able to make array `A` and `B` as a shared memory (maybe using `multiprocessing.Array()` ??) , and then make multiple processes to compute the `function(A, B)`. But i still can't quite understand how to put all of that in the code.

**EDIT:**

Alright, so it seems like the approach above doesn't work, but let's try another case, but now, lets say the length of array `A` is 120, and now i want to use only 3/4 parts of array `A` from index number *0 to 89* and use all of array `B` in the Process No.1

And then, i also want to use 3/4 parts of array `A` but from index number *30 to 119* and use all parts of array `B` in the Process No.2, will that help? Of course i can make the `A` array even larger to get it's part computed with even more process where, but the thing is, will this concept works?

Comment: "It works as it is but it's slow and i think we can use multiprocessing to make it a bit faster." probably not. `np.einsum` is probably the fastest approach you will be able to find for something like this.

Comment: ah my bad, actually it's an numpy array, i'll edit that

Comment: I'm not sure how `np.einsum` is implemented, but I can only assume that fundamentally, the performance will depend on the exact BLAS/LAPACK backend, which could already be parallelized anyway. I am skeptical `multiprocessing` will be helpful here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga alright, but let's say i want to run 2 different functions that does different thing , that also uses array `A` and `B` as an input, can i use multiprocess to do that ?

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to do in more detail. Yes, you can use multiprocessing to run functions in different processes.

Comment: the function is still the same, but i want to try another approach, i already edited the post :)